# WCFExtras web.config pointing (my) external service

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I am trying to use WCFExtras to obtain single file WSDL from my service (ExternalOrderService.svc).

I've modified the original web.config from WCFExtras SampleServer project adding the reference to my service. The ServerSample works right, and I succed in calling the Sample.WsdlSample wsdl file, but I don't succed in calling my service wsdl.
What's wrong in the following configuration?

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Sample.WsdlSampleBehavior" name="Sample.WsdlSample">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Sample.WsdlSampleEndpointBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Sample.IWsdlSample"/>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Sample.SoapHeadersSampleBehavior" name="Sample.SoapHeadersSample">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Sample.SoapHeadersSampleEndpointBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Sample.ISoapHeadersSample"/>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ExternalOrderServiceBehavior" name="ExternalOrderService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Monclick.MVC2.Services.External.IExternalOrderService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Sample.WsdlSampleEndpointBehavior">
          <wsdlExtensions location="http://127.0.0.1/Sample/WsdlSample.svc" singleFile="True"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="Sample.SoapHeadersSampleEndpointBehavior">
          <wsdlExtensions location="http://127.0.0.1/Sample/SoapHeadersSample.svc"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="ExternalOrderServiceBehavior">
          <wsdlExtensions location="http://api.local/Services/ExternalOrderService.svc" singleFile="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Sample.WsdlSampleBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="false"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="Sample.SoapHeadersSampleBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="ExternalOrderServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />   
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <!-- Declare that we have an extension called WSDL Extras-->
        <add name="wsdlExtensions" type="WCFExtras.Wsdl.WsdlExtensionsConfig, WCFExtras, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this section of code:

```
 <service behaviorConfiguration="ExternalOrderServiceBehavior" name="ExternalOrderService"> 
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Monclick.MVC2.Services.External.IExternalOrderService" /> 
  </service>
```

You have not defined the `behaviorConfiguration` for the endpoint of your service. Change to this and it should work:

```
 <service behaviorConfiguration="ExternalOrderServiceBehavior" name="ExternalOrderService"> 
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ExternalOrderServiceBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Monclick.MVC2.Services.External.IExternalOrderService" /> 
  </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the address. The services that work have "127.0.0.1" the one that does not work has "api.local".

Try replacing "api.local" with "127.0.0.1".

The other thing I see is that you don not have any mex endpoints defined.

Comment: Isn't it possible to refer to a remote service? Let's say to api.local?

Comment: yes if api.local is a registered dns name, but it does not look like a dns name, although it could be.